# Performing go routines in background

Tags: heroku, go, backgroundworker

I am new to Go and I am using go routines in my app in Heroku, which are long (up to 7 minutes), and cannot be interrupted. 
I saw that the auto scaler sometimes kills the Heroku dyno which is running the routine. I need a way of running this routine independently from the dynos so I know that it will not get shutdown. I read articles and still don't understand how to perform a go routine in a background worker. It is hard for me to believe I am the only one experiencing this.
My go routines use my redis database.

Could someone please point me to an example of how to setup a background worker in heroku for go and how to send my go routine to that worker?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

> I need a way of running this routine independently from the dynos so I
>   know that it will not get shutdown.

If you don't want to run your worker code on a dyno then you'll need to use a different provider from Heroku, like Amazon AWS, Digital Ocean, Linode etc.

Having said that, you should design your workers, especially those that are mission critical, to be able to recover from a shutdown. Either to be able to continue where they left off or to start over. Heroku's dyno manager restarts the dynos at least once a day but I wouldn't be surprised if the other cloud providers also restart their virtual instances once in a while, probably not once a day but still... And even if you decide to deploy your workers on a physical machine that you control and never turn off, you cannot prevent things like hardware failure or power outage from happening.

If your workers need to perform some task till it's done you need to make them be aware of possible shutdowns and have them handle such scenarios gracefully. Do not ever rely on a machine, physical or virtual, to keep running while your worker is doing it's job.

For example if you're on Heroku, use a [worker dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing) and make your worker listen for the `SIGTERM` signal, after your worker receives such a signal...

> The application processes have 30 seconds to shut down cleanly
>   (ideally, they will do so more quickly than that). During this time
>   they should stop accepting new requests or jobs and attempt to finish
>   their current requests, or put jobs back on the queue for other worker
>   processes to handle. If any processes remain after that time period,
>   the dyno manager will terminate them forcefully with `SIGKILL`.

... continue reading [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#shutdown).

But keep in mind, as I mentioned earlier, if there is an outage and Heroku goes down, which is something that happens from time to time, your worker won't even have those 30 seconds to clean up.

Comment: Thank you, I know I cannot rely on any machine and that's why I wanted to know how to handle this.